# When to Use Custom Migration compared to Lightweight Migration in CoreData (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm creating an application with Core Data. Until now I'm using the lightweight migration for my CoreData migration.

1. May I know when I should use custom migration?
2. Any drawback in lightweight migration compared to custom migration?

Answer (score 1):

My short answer is the following.

The light migration occurs at SQLite level and it is handled automatically (you need to set right options parameters when you create the store). There are no objects loaded into memory and memory requirements are low. In general such type of migration is (very) fast.

On the contrary the heavy migration is more difficult than the first one. Performing it, it means load each entity into memory, translate
it from the old store to the new one, and finally write it back out to disk. Usually it is performed in background and, since it could take time, you should warn the user that some type of processing is going on. It requires more work performed by the developer since he needs to say to Core Data how to migrate.

Said this, **[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH1-SW1) is your friend**. For example, about the first type of migration says:

> Lightweight migration is especially convenient during early stages of
>   application development, when you may be changing your managed object
>   model frequently, but you don’t want to have to keep regenerating test
>   data. You can migrate existing data without having to create a custom
>   mapping model for every model version used to create a store that
>   would need to be migrated.

In addition, you could find other references googling a littel bit.

- [Lightweight Migration](http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration)
- [Custom Migration](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-migration.html)

**Edit 1**

To summarize. Custom is more complicated. *As a developer you have the responsibility to specify how Core Data needs to migrate*. So, you need to do it manually. It's slow and usually it requires a lot of time to understand what is going on. On the contrary light is automatic and fast. You need to set only to options and Core Data will take care for you. See also **Marcus Zarra** comment. In particular,

> In addition, you should avoid heavy migration in all cases on iOS as
>   it was not originally designed to run on iOS devices and causes more
>   problems than it is worth. If you cannot use a lightweight migration
>   (which is the best option) then doing an export/import is far better
>   than doing a beavy-weight migration.

Comment: In addition, you should avoid heavy migration in all cases on iOS as it was not originally designed to run on iOS devices and causes more problems than it is worth.  If you cannot use a lightweight migration (which is the best option) then doing an export/import is far better than doing a beavy-weight migration.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra perfectly agree with you. Custom migration can be very difficult to achieve. It requires time and a good knowledge of Core Data. I don't how many people are able to use it, except you, obviuosly ;)

Comment: And I don't use it :)

Comment: @flexaddicted Me too learned the migration with link you have mentioned here. but I want to know any drawback in using lightweight migration compared to custom?

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I've inserted your comment in my edit. Let me know if I can leave it within my answer. I'm think the import/export advice is very useful. Cheers.